# Kubernetes pod failed to update

Tags: kubernetes

We have a Gitlab CI/CD to deploy pod via Kubernetes. However, the updated pod is always pending and the deleted pod is always stuck at terminating.
[image]

The controller and scheduler are both okay.
[image]

If I described the pending pod, it shows it is scheduled but nothing else.
[image]

This is the pending pod's logs:

> $ kubectl logs -f robo-apis-dev-7b79ccf74b-nr9q2 -n xxx -f Error from
> server (BadRequest): container "robo-apis-dev" in pod
> "robo-apis-dev-7b79ccf74b-nr9q2" is waiting to start:
> ContainerCreating

What could be the issue? Our Kubernetes cluster never had this issue before.

Comment: Without seeing the logs of that pod it's impossible to help you... It could be anything...

Comment: Is your pod is supposed to stay up ?
What happen if you summon it on docker for example ?
Do you have an healthcheck on the deploy/pod definition ?
Seems like it time out seeing the Pending for 19min and terminating at 26min.

Comment: @Swifty I added the logs

Comment: So... This is not really an error message... It just hangs... The question is: why? :(

Comment: Yeah, it just hangs. We are not sure either.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it turns out we used to have an NFS server as PVC. But we have moved to AWS EKS recently, thus cleaning the NFS servers. Maybe there are some resources from nodes that are still on the NFS server. Once we temporarily roll back the NFS server, the pods start to move to RUNNING state.

The issue was discussed here - Orphaned pod https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60987